# Run method annotated with AfterMethod only after specified Test method in testng

Tags: java, testing, annotations, testng

I have this example code:

```
public class A {

@BeforeTest(groups = "group1")
public void beforeTest() {
    System.out.println("Before test");
}

@BeforeMethod(groups = "group1")
public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("Before method");
}

@Test(groups = { "group1" })
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("Test1");
}

@Test(groups = {"group2"})
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("Test2");
}

@AfterMethod(groups = { "group2" }, alwaysRun = false)
public void afterMethod() {
    System.out.println("After method");
}

@AfterTest(groups = "grupa1")
public void afterTest() {
    System.out.println("AfterTest");
}
}
```

And the output is:

```
Before test
Before method
Test1
After method
Before method
Test2
After method
AfterTest
```

But I would like to recieve something like this:

```
Before test
Before method
Test1
Before method
Test2
After method
AfterTest
```

Is there any option to call afterMethod method only after second test method? I can't use afterGroup annotation.

Comment: You should tailor your solution here. May be a shared variable / flag which represents whether to run test or not and check this flag as first line in `After Method` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@AfterMethod` by `@AfterClass` and you will have the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dependsOnGroups`
For exapmle if you want to run method only after group2 tests use this:

```
@AfterMethod(dependsOnGroups = {"group2"})
```

The same should works for `@Before` configurations